# Как правильно расположить элемент при касании экрана?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Когда я нажимаю на экран, я получаю координаты нажатия, после чего, хочу переместить туда свой TextView, но почему-то он перемещается крайне странно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии в то место, которое я отметил точкой, надпись у меня перемещается немного в неправильное место, хотя координаты правильные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. x - показывает, ось x, куда я нажал пальцем
2. y - показывает, ось y, куда я нажал пальцем
3. text_x - показывает, ось x, где находится textview
4. text_y - показывает, ось y, где находится textview
5. Final text x - показывает, ось x, куда "по итогу" переместился TextView
6. Final text y - показывает, ось y, куда "по итогу" переместился TextView

Вот main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintlay"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    >

    <TextView
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:id="@+id/movingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:onClick="stopAction"
        android:text="HELLO"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И сам java код

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{

    float x =  event.getRawX();
    float y =  event.getRawY();

    Log.e("x", String.valueOf(x));
    Log.e("y", String.valueOf(y));
    Log.e("text x", String.valueOf(textView.getX()));
    Log.e("text y", String.valueOf(textView.getY()));


    textView.setX(x);
    textView.setY(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно, неправильно... а как надо то?
`MotionEvent.getRawX()` даёт координаты относительно верхнего левого угла **экрана**
`View.setX(x)` задаёт позицию вью относительно **контейнера**, в котором эта вью расположена.
Вывод: нужно учитывать позицию контейнера относительно экрана, либо вешать слушатель на сам контейнер и брать координаты методами `getX()`, `getY()`

Comment: Ну textView отображается в ином месте, хотя все координаты правильно указаны.

А как повесить правильно повесить слушатель ?